# Java nested classes размещение в памяти

Tags: java, static

у меня возник вопрос, который не дает мне покоя, а именно:

1. Статические методы и поля принадлежат классу, а не экземпляру класса и хранятся в PermGen -> ("MetaSpace").
2. Мы не можем делать статические классы но можем делать nested classes.
3. Мы свободно можем создавать экземпляры nested классов в любом количестве так, будто это обычный Java объект который хранится в хипе.

Может кто-то знает, где в памяти хранятся nested классы?

Comment: Вот про пункт 2 я не понял. Что может помешать вам объявить `public static class StaticClass { ... }` внутри другого класса?

Comment: Если уточнить мой пункт № 2, то - статическими, мы можем делать только вложенные классы в другой класс. Вот

Answer (score 1):

Member Class - это такой же класс, как и top-level класс, и храниться должен там же, где хранятся определения классов.

Единственное отличие нестатических классов, объявленных внутри других классов, заключается в том, что при генерации байткода во вложенные классы добавляется ссылка на родительский объект.

```
package org.example;

class TopLevel
{
   private int data;

   public TopLevel(int _data)
   {
      data = _data;
   }

   class MemberClass
   {
       public int getData() {
           return data;
       }
   }

   MemberClass getMemberClassInstance()
   {
      return new MemberClass();
   }
}
```

Распечатаем утилитой `javap` содержимое сгенерированного .class файла:

```
pakuula:/home/pakuula/eclipse-workspace/MemberClass/bin/org/example$ javap 'TopLevel$MemberClass.class'
```

Вывод команды:

```
Compiled from "TopLevel.java"
class org.example.TopLevel$MemberClass {
  final org.example.TopLevel this$0;
  org.example.TopLevel$MemberClass(org.example.TopLevel);
  public int getData();
}
```

Компилятор добавил ссылку на объект внешнего класса `final org.example.TopLevel this$0;` и инициализирует её в конструкторе.

В методе `MemberClass.getData()` эта ссылка используется для доступа к приватному полю `data` родительского объекта. Вот байткод конструктора и метода `getData` (результат работы `javap -v`):

```
  org.example.TopLevel$MemberClass(org.example.TopLevel);
    descriptor: (Lorg/example/TopLevel;)V
    flags:
    Code:
      stack=2, locals=2, args_size=2
         0: aload_0
         1: aload_1
         2: putfield      #10                 // Field this$0:Lorg/example/TopLevel;
         5: aload_0
         6: invokespecial #12                 // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
         9: return

  public int getData();
    descriptor: ()I
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC
    Code:
      stack=1, locals=1, args_size=1
         0: aload_0
         1: getfield      #10                 // Field this$0:Lorg/example/TopLevel;
         4: getfield      #21                 // Field org/example/TopLevel.data:I
         7: ireturn
```

Так что ничего особенного во вложенных классах Java нет. Они компилируются статически и хранятся вместе со всеми остальными классами. Для доступа к полям родительского объекта в них внедряется ссылка на родительский объект.

Кстати, эта ссылка может быть причиной раздувания памяти. Родительский объект не будет удалён сборщиком мусора до тех пор, пока не будут удалены все объекты вложенного класса. Поэтому если в родительском объекте есть много всякой всячины, то это будет болтаться в памяти, даже если объект вложенного класса этим не пользуется.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ! С внутренними классами вопросов какраз и не возникает. Вопросы возникают с "вложенными" == "nested" == "static class". Сама концепция static предполагает наличие одной и только одной сущности в рантайме нашего приложения. В то же время, мы можем получать любое количество экземпляров nested классов, не смотря на то, что nested классы это статическая сущность. Как это вообще возможно?

Comment: Строго говоря, "nested" != "inner static". Согласно Java Lang Spec, *[nested classes include] member classes (§8.5, §9.5), local classes (§14.3) and anonymous classes (§15.9.5)* Ключевое слово `static` в определении внутреннего класса означает, что методы этого класса не могут использовать нестатические поля и методы объемлющего класса (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.5.1). Другими словами, в определении такого класса нет неявной ссылки на родительский объект. Но это никак не мешает создавать экземпляры такого класса.